# Shifting arrays - PHP

Tags: php

I am working on a project of mine and have a hardware based component that sends data back that I gather and through that arrays are created.  One function is comparing data within one array and another.  Something I have come across that is bothersome is it always seems to place a value in a the `2` index of the array due to just how it is looping through.  My question is, the values `0 and 1` in that array have nothing in them.  They are offset.  How could I move that value in the index `2` to index `0` of the array, or in a more dynamic way; put it in the first available slot.

Thoughts and suggestions are appreciate.

EDIT:

`Array ( [2] => 0x0000000000000000004004490529 )` - This is output using a print_r()

UPDATE:

Here is what is the output as it iterates through the array:

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in daemon.php on line 259

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in daemon.php on line 259
```

Comment: TLDR; where's your code?

Comment: [array_shift](http://php.net/array_shift)?

Comment: some code or a sample output will be easy to help you

Comment: Sorry totally forgot about the code.

Comment: @Nanne what I mean is output, excuse my english.

Comment: It shouldn't really matter, you either loop through your array or get the first (or last) element using something like `array_shift` or `reset`. If the keys are not important, just don't use them. Either way your code should not depend on the numerical indices.

Comment: I'm simply telling you because it might be a necessity to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$array = array_merge($array);
```

This will reindex your array from 0

```
$array = array(2 => 'foo'); // your starting point
$array = array_merge($array);
var_dump($array);
// array(1) { [0]=> string(3) "foo" }
```

Or if you only have one key and it's always in index 2 you can also do it the simple way:

```
$array = array(2 => 'foo'); // your starting point
$array[0] = $array[2];
unset($array[2]);
```

Comment: But the value wont be always in index 2, It just depends on how many fields are in a database so how can I dynamically set that?

Comment: @DavidBiga array_merge doesn't depend on it being in key 2. Whatever the key is in, it will always re-index in 0. Try it.

Comment: it worked great, I probably should of looked for something like this. Thanks again, you get the points :)

Answer (score 2):

You can reset all the keys by using [`array_values`](http://www.php.net/array_values):

```
$array = array_values($array);
```

**Example:**

```
<?php
    $array = array(
        0 => 'baz',
        2 => 'foo',
        4 => 'bar'
    );

    $array = array_values($array);

    print_r($array);
    /*
        Array
        (
            [0] => baz
            [1] => foo
            [2] => bar
        )
    */
?>
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/8RisdB4J)

Essentially what `array_values` does (if one were to recode it in PHP) is this:

```
function array_values($array) {
    $return = array();

    foreach ($array as $value) {
        $return[] = $value;
    }

    return $return;
}
```